# apacheds: Imported custom object classes not visible

Tags: ldap, schema, apacheds, ldif

I am running an ldapv3 server on apacheds2.0.0 using Apache Directory Studio. I have successfully imported a schema that defines my own custom object classes, Here is an example from the schema:

```
objectclass ( 7.7.7.7
    NAME 'Dog' 
    SUP Animal
    STRUCTURAL 
    MUST dogName 
    MAY ( lead$ collar$ house$ age$ color$ etc$) 
 )
```

When I start up the server and try to add a new `Dog` entry the objectClass `Dog` is not an option.

[image]

Does something else need to be done programatically or otherwise, before my custom object classes can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-loading the schema from the connection properties.

right-click on the connection, `properties->connection->schema->reload schema`

Comment: right-click on the connection, properties->connection->schema->reload schema

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Click the **reload** button and see you custom schema object.